# How to access content provider of another application

Tags: android-contentprovider

**I have created the content provider application. I want to use the content provider in another  application.  Any permissions required in the application for accessing the content provider.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to give following permissions in **manifest** file:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.permRead" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.permWrite"
```